# Scroll is not detected in embedded ScrollView when Autolayout is enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

**LAYOUT A** - Scroll detected in both Scrollviews

-View
----ScrollView1
------ContentView1
----ScrollView2
------ContentView2

**LAYOUT B** - Scroll not detected in ScrollView2

-View
---ScrollView1
-----ContentView1
--------ScrollView2
----------ContentView2

With layout A both Scrollviews works with Autolayout enabled.
With layout B ScrollView2 does not work with Autolayout enabled.

When trying both layouts i'm running this code to set the contentSizes:

```c
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.scrollView1.contentSize = self.contentView1.frame.size;
    self.scrollView2.contentSize = self.contentView2.frame.size;
}
```

How can I get the scrollview in layout B working with Autolayout enabled?

I'm using iOS 7.1

Comment: To clarify. With Autolayout enabled I mean it's just checked to be used in my project. There is no constraints added (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Adding constraints correctly solved the problem.
This video was very helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oCWxHLBQ-A